Excel VBA create 2 temp tables and enter the output into a third temp table and output to excel sheet
Outputting data from sql query as below:
//Comments: Create first temp table #qcdbTemp1 for test replicate 1
select s1.TEXT_ID as [OrigSamp] ,s2.TEXT_ID as [DupSamp1], cast(r1.FORMATTED_ENTRY as float) as [OrigRes], cast(r2.FORMATTED_ENTRY as float) as [DupRes1], 
(ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by s1.TEXT_ID order by s1.TEXT_ID desc)) as ID  
INTO #qcdbTemp1
from SAMPLE s1 
join SAMPLE s2 on s1.SAMPLE_NUMBER = s2.SAMPLE_NUMBER 
join TEST t1 on t1.SAMPLE_NUMBER = s1.SAMPLE_NUMBER  and t1.REPLICATE_COUNT = 1 
join RESULT r1 on r1.TEST_NUMBER = t1.TEST_NUMBER and r1.REPLICATE_COUNT = 1 
join RESULT r2 on r2.TEST_NUMBER = t1.TEST_NUMBER and r1.NAME = r2.NAME and r2.REPLICATE_COUNT > 1 
where s2.SAMPLE_NAME <> 'DUP' and s1.SAMPLE_NAME <> 'DUP'  and s1.TEXT_ID = 'A' 
and r1.ANALYSIS in ('Density')  and r2.ANALYSIS in ('Density') and r1.REPORTABLE = 'T' 
and r1.NAME in ('BSG') and r2.NAME in ('BSG')

//Comments: Create second temp table #qcdbTemp2 for test replicate 2
select s1.TEXT_ID as [OrigSamp] ,s2.TEXT_ID as [DupSamp1], cast(r1.FORMATTED_ENTRY as float) as [OrigRes], cast(r2.FORMATTED_ENTRY as float) as [DupRes1], 
(ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by s1.TEXT_ID order by s1.TEXT_ID desc)) as ID  
INTO #qcdbTemp2
from SAMPLE s1 
join SAMPLE s2 on s1.SAMPLE_NUMBER = s2.SAMPLE_NUMBER 
join TEST t1 on t1.SAMPLE_NUMBER = s1.SAMPLE_NUMBER  and t1.REPLICATE_COUNT = 2 
join RESULT r1 on r1.TEST_NUMBER = t1.TEST_NUMBER and r1.REPLICATE_COUNT = 1 
join RESULT r2 on r2.TEST_NUMBER = t1.TEST_NUMBER and r1.NAME = r2.NAME and r2.REPLICATE_COUNT > 1 
where s2.SAMPLE_NAME <> 'DUP' and s1.SAMPLE_NAME <> 'DUP'  and s1.TEXT_ID = 'A' 
and r1.ANALYSIS in ('Density') and r2.ANALYSIS in ('Density')  and r1.REPORTABLE = 'T' 
and r1.NAME in ('BSG') and r2.NAME in ('BSG')

//Combine the output from the temp tables to the excel sheet and then drop the two temp tables.
Select   distinct OrigSamp ,
(select OrigRes from #qcdbTemp1 r0 where r0.OrigSamp = #qcdbTemp1.OrigSamp and ID=1 ) res0 , 
 (select DupRes1 from #qcdbTemp1 r1 where r1.OrigSamp = #qcdbTemp1.OrigSamp and ID=1 ) res1 ,
  (select DupRes1 from #qcdbTemp1 r2 where r2.OrigSamp = #qcdbTemp1.OrigSamp and ID=2 ) res2 

 from #qcdbTemp1  where 
 (select DupSamp1 from #qcdbTemp1 a1 where a1.OrigSamp = #qcdbTemp1.OrigSamp and ID=1) is not null 

 union all 

 Select   distinct OrigSamp ,
(select OrigRes from #qcdbTemp2 r0 where r0.OrigSamp = #qcdbTemp2.OrigSamp and ID=1 ) res0 , 
 (select DupRes1 from #qcdbTemp2 r1 where r1.OrigSamp = #qcdbTemp2.OrigSamp and ID=1 ) res1,
 (select DupRes1 from #qcdbTemp2 r2 where r2.OrigSamp = #qcdbTemp2.OrigSamp and ID=2 ) res2 

 from #qcdbTemp2  where 
 (select DupSamp1 from #qcdbTemp2 a1 where a1.OrigSamp = #qcdbTemp2.OrigSamp and ID=1) is not null 
drop table #qcdbTemp1 
drop table #qcdbTemp2


NEED HELP with the following:

sql query solution to get unique IDs so that I can manage with one temp table instead of 2. This will make it easier to get the final output.


Here's how you can get all the temp table data into one table.
Add t1.REPLICATE_COUNT to the row number partition...
(ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t1.REPLICATE_COUNT, s1.TEXT_ID order by s1.TEXT_ID desc)) as ID,

And to the SELECT list...
t1.REPLICATE_COUNT as TestReplicateCount

Then change the join of TEST to...
join TEST t1 
    on t1.SAMPLE_NUMBER = s1.SAMPLE_NUMBER  
    and t1.REPLICATE_COUNT IN (1, 2)  -- Assuming there are other values that you don't want

Full query...
select 
    s1.TEXT_ID as [OrigSamp], 
    s2.TEXT_ID as [DupSamp1], 
    cast(r1.FORMATTED_ENTRY as float) as [OrigRes], 
    cast(r2.FORMATTED_ENTRY as float) as [DupRes1], 
    (ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t1.REPLICATE_COUNT, s1.TEXT_ID order by s1.TEXT_ID desc)) as ID,
    t1.REPLICATE_COUNT as TestReplicateCount
INTO #qcdbTemp
from SAMPLE s1 
join SAMPLE s2 
    on s1.SAMPLE_NUMBER = s2.SAMPLE_NUMBER 
join TEST t1 
    on t1.SAMPLE_NUMBER = s1.SAMPLE_NUMBER  
    and t1.REPLICATE_COUNT IN (1, 2) 
join RESULT r1 
    on r1.TEST_NUMBER = t1.TEST_NUMBER 
    and r1.REPLICATE_COUNT = 1 
join RESULT r2 
    on r2.TEST_NUMBER = t1.TEST_NUMBER 
    and r1.NAME = r2.NAME 
    and r2.REPLICATE_COUNT > 1 
where s2.SAMPLE_NAME <> 'DUP' 
and s1.SAMPLE_NAME <> 'DUP'  
and s1.TEXT_ID = 'A' 
and r1.ANALYSIS in ('Density')  
and r2.ANALYSIS in ('Density') 
and r1.REPORTABLE = 'T' 
and r1.NAME in ('BSG') 
and r2.NAME in ('BSG')

You'll then need to change your output query to use the new TestReplicateCount column.
